# IE or Firefox not autoresizing

Tags: image, firefox, html, tags, image-resizing

First off, I'm new to this and have been doing a lot of research, but can't find the answer.

I have set a div container at the top of my page to 100% width and 20% height.
I wanted to insert an image which would resize automatically across screen sizes.

I found some code on this site which works perfectly in safari and chrome (also resizes perfectly on an ipad and iphone) but in firefox(20) and IE(10) the image does resize slightly but wont stay in the parent container.

Can anyone help?
The original code I have been using is:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
#myDiv 
{
height:auto;
width:auto;
}
#myDiv img
{
max-width:100%; 
max-height:100%;
margin:auto;
display:block;
}
</style>


<div id="myDiv">
<img src="images/storm.jpg">
</div>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated (and please remember I'm learning!)

Answer (score 0):

```
#myDiv img
{
width:100%; 
height:100%;
margin:auto;
display:block;
}
```

You need to set the actual width/height of the image to 100%, not the max-width and max-height.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it doesn't work, it just stretches the image.
From what I can see, the image is bound to the size of the container div tag in Safari and Chrome, but this is ignored in IE and Firefox, so you get the image to be 100% of its size ignoring the container size, so it wont resize when this is shrunk or expanded.
Any other ideas?